# Command Prompt data Garbled

Tags: vb.net, shell, process, vb.net-2010, command-prompt

I finally have my code working after fixing tons of bugs, but I still get a few minor problems

```
Dim myprocess As New System.Diagnostics.Process
myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
myprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
myprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
myprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
myprocess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\"
myprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
myprocess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
myprocess.Start()

myprocess.StandardInput.WriteLine(prompt.Text)
myprocess.StandardInput.Flush()
myprocess.StandardInput.Close()

prompt.Text = ""
prompt.Text = myprocess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd

myprocess.StandardOutput.Dispose()
myprocess.StandardOutput.Close()

myprocess.WaitForExit()
myprocess.Close()
```

The problem is, if I execute a command such as "TREE", it is unable to interpret the lines that make up the tree. Executing "TREE /A" fixes the problem, but I want to know why just plain old "TREE" doesn't get interpreted right.

Also, once I execute a command such as "TREE", I am unable to type in my textbox until I use my Clear function. Interestingly I am able to Backspace but not type.

Paste this code into VB.NET and add a textbox and button. You will see what I mean.

1. Why does the text become garbled?
2. Why am I unable to type in my textbox?

Answer (score 3):

Your text is garbled because your program isn't using the right [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) to decode the bytes being read from the output stream. The [TREE](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tree.mspx?mfr=true) command uses graphical characters to represent the lines linking subdirectories, but these code points only represent line-drawing characters in [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), the native MS-DOS (US English) code page. The `/A` switch makes the TREE command use standard ASCII characters instead.

Comment: Interesting, so how do I specify "code page 437". Is it possible? Do you know an example for vb.net?

Comment: Rather than reading from `myprocess.StandardOutput`, I'd try something like `Dim output As New StreamReader(myprocess.StandardOutput.BaseStream, New System.Text.Encoding(437))` and read from that instead.

Comment: Apparantly 'New' cannot be used on a class that is declared 'MustInherit'. This is the error I get. Are you sure you are allowed to specify 437? I thought you could only chose from VB.NETs list such as UTF8, Big Endian...

Comment: Sorry about that - should have been `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(437)`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzsz3bk3.aspx.

Comment: Worked like a charm man, you are the bomb!!! Also, do you happen to know why my text box freezes up once the "TREE" command executes? Everything outputs fine but it doesn't allow me to type, only backspace? This doesn't happen on commands such as "CD".

Comment: It's because the default value of the TextBox control's `MaxLength` property is 32767, and from the level you're running `TREE`, i.e., `C:\\`, you're putting more than 32767 characters in the text box. Set the MaxLength property to zero and you should find that you can type.